# Add a responsive three-panel slider to hugo

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, hugo

I'm trying to add a slider to my Hugo website that shows three images in a row, and slides to the next set of three images once a button is pressed.  If the screen size is small, the slider responds by showing one image at a time.

I was able to make a single-panel slider work in Hugo by adopting tbiering's [hugo slider shortcode](https://github.com/tbiering/hugo-slider-shortcode.git). I was not able to modify it to include three images because I'm not familiar with jquery. Instead, I replaced the content of tbeiring's `gallery-slider.html` page with [this code](https://usefulangle.com/post/313/css-flex-order-carousel-infinite).  I choose this because it uses a flexbox, which makes me think it is more likely to be responsive, and because it is written in javascript, which I have some familiarity with.

The code makes a functional slider, but only shows the alt text.  Here's how I have tried to add the image:

`<div class="slider-item" data-position="1"><img src="NS1.jpg" alt="Bird on a tree"></div>`

I cannot figure out which folder should hold the image file.  I have tried:

- in `content/static` (where images usually live in Hugo);
- in the same folder as the page that references the shortcode;
- in the same folder as the one containing the shortcode.
- in any folder, with the absolute path referenced.
- as a background-image as part of the css ie. `background-image:url('file:////path/to/image/NS1.jpg')`;

To be clear, the path to the image file is correct; it shows up when I plug it into the file browser.

Your help is much appreciated.

---

Update:

I went back to tbiering's script, with the idea that I could set up a flexbox parent div holding three empty child divs. For each empty child div, I could loop through the images in the folder and make the code stop the loop so that the first empty div shows the first image, the second empty div shows the second image, etc.  The problem is that I can't quite stop the loop, and I'm getting something that looks like this:
[image]

I've attached the code; due to the absence of a place to put the markdown, it doesn't actually function.

```js
sliderJQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
sliderJQuery(function($) {
  $.global = new Object();
  $.global.total = 0;

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var slideWindowWidth = $('#slide-window').width();
    var slideCount = $('#slides-list li').length;
    var totalSlidesWidth = slideCount * slideWindowWidth;

    $.global.item = 0;
    $.global.total = slideCount;

    $('.slide').css('width', slideWindowWidth + 'px');
    $('#slides-list').css('width', totalSlidesWidth + 'px');

    $('#left').click(function() {
      resetAutoSlide();
      performSlide('back');
    });

    $('#right').click(function() {
      resetAutoSlide();
      performSlide('forward');
    });

  });

  function performSlide(direction) {
    if (direction == 'back') {
      var nextSlideId = $.global.item - 1;
    }
    if (direction == 'forward') {
      var nextSlideId = $.global.item + 1;
    }

    if (nextSlideId == -1) {
      /* At first position and requesting 'back' -> Go to last item */
      moveCss($.global.total - 1);
    } else if (nextSlideId == $.global.total) {
      /* At last position and requesting 'forward' -> Go to first item */
      moveCss(0);
    } else {
      /* Move to requested item */
      moveCss(nextSlideId);
    }
  }

  function moveCss(nextSlideId) {
    var slideWindowWidth = $('#slide-window').width();
    var margin = slideWindowWidth * nextSlideId;

    $('#slides-list').css('transform', 'translate3d(-' + margin + 'px,0px,0px)');

    $.global.item = nextSlideId;
  }

  {
    {
      if ne(.Get "auto-slide")
      "0"
    }
  }
  var autoSlide = parseInt({
    {
      $.Scratch.Get "auto-slide"
    }
  }, 10);
  var autoSlideInterval;

  function resetAutoSlide() {
    if (autoSlide) {
      if (autoSlideInterval) {
        clearInterval(autoSlideInterval);
      }
      autoSlideInterval = setInterval(function() {
        performSlide('forward');
      }, autoSlide)
    }
  }
  resetAutoSlide();

  {
    {
      -end
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#slide-window {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1080px;
}

#emptyplaceholder {
  width: {
    {
      $.Scratch.Get "width"
    }
  }
  ;
  height: {
    {
      $.Scratch.Get "height"
    }
  }
  ;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

#slides-list {
  width: {
    {
      $.Scratch.Get "width"
    }
  }
  ;
  height: {
    {
      $.Scratch.Get "height"
    }
  }
  ;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  transition: all 0.66s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.66s ease;
}

.slide {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: {
    {
      $.Scratch.Get "width"
    }
  }
  ;
  height: {
    {
      $.Scratch.Get "height"
    }
  }
  ;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.nav {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 45%;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: grey;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: all 0.66s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.66s ease;
}

.nav:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

#left {
  left: -25%;
  float: left;
  background: transparent;
}

#right {
  right: -25%;
  float: right;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="slide-window">
  <div id="emptyplaceholder">div1</div>
  {{- with (.Get "dir") -}} {{- $files := readDir (print "/static/" .) }} {{- range $files -}} {{- $absoluteUrl := print ($.Get "dir") "/" .Name | absURL }}
  <li class="slide" style="background-image:url({{ $absoluteUrl }});"></li>
  {{- end }} {{- end }}
  <div id="emptyplaceholder">div2</div>
  {{- with (.Get "dir") -}} {{- $files := readDir (print "/static/" .) }} {{- range $files -}} {{- $absoluteUrl := print ($.Get "dir") "/" .Name | absURL }}
  <li class="slide" style="background-image:url({{ $absoluteUrl }});"></li>
  {{- end }} {{- end }}
  <div id="emptyplaceholder">div3</div>
  {{- with (.Get "dir") -}} {{- $files := readDir (print "/static/" .) }} {{- range $files -}} {{- $absoluteUrl := print ($.Get "dir") "/" .Name | absURL }}
  <li class="slide" style="background-image:url({{ $absoluteUrl }});"></li>
  {{- end }} {{- end }}

  <span class="nav fa {{ $.Scratch.Get " arrow-left " }} fa-3x" id="left"></span>
  <span class="nav fa {{ $.Scratch.Get " arrow-right " }} fa-3x" id="right"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `static/` directory is by default not accessible using the `.Resources` function, so you are currently trying to read the `static/` directory to get access to the image parameters.

What you should do, is putting the images in the `assets/` directory of your site. By doing so, you can access an image as a ressource by its name, and have access to property such as `.RelPermalink`, `.Width` and `.Height`

```
{{ $image := .Resources.GetMatch "sunset.jpg" }}
{{ with $image }}
  <img src="{{ .RelPermalink }}" width="{{ .Width }}" height="{{ .Height }}">
{{ end }}
```

If you need to keep your images in the static/ folder, you can mount the `static/` directory for it be accessible using the `.Resources` function, as well as `assets/`

```
# Mount the static dir to the assets, to be able to fetch the static files as assets and merge them together
[module]
[[module.mounts]]
  source = 'static/css'
  target = 'assets/css'
```

More information in the Hugo doc here:
https://gohugo.io/hugo-modules/configuration/#module-config-mounts